# How can I prevent clicking on 'Add to Cart' from opening the product page on my online shop built with Elementor, Crockoblock and Woocommerce?

Tags: events, woocommerce, product, elementor

I'm building an online shop with woocommerce/elementor/crockoblock.

I customized the product aspect on archive page with crockoblock.

Basically, its the product image, and then when you hover the image the "Add to Cart" button appears on the bottom of the product image. However, when i click the "Add to Cart" button, besides adding that product to the cart, it also opens the product page. It's like the click is assuming the button and the image behind it at the sime time and triggering the two events together.

I would like to find a way to make sure the click only adds to cart and does not open the product page, mantaining the image clickable too when the user would like to see the product page. Could you help me?

It seems that the problem it's not in the hover effect. If i remove it, the click triggers the two events anyway.

Also, I managed to block the image event in the configurations, but that's not what i'm really looking for. The image should still be clickable.

Comment: In WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products make sure your "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives" is checked.

Comment: Yes, that is checked, doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Sounds more like theme related issue.